# create a composite unique index when column=value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an index on a table that is working fine

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uk_index ON my_table (nbr, extract(year from date_));
```

now something new came up and the trigger only works when the new entry is accepted, I added a new column `accepted`, I can add as many entries as I wanted with the same `nbr` and same `year` as long as they are not accepted, but only one can have the same `nbr`, `year` and be `accepted`, something like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uk_index ON my_table (case when accepted=1 then nbr, extract(year from date_));
```

Comment: What "trigger" are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the same condition for another column also with complete CASE syntax -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uk_index ON my_table (CASE WHEN accepted=1 THEN nbr ELSE NULL END, 
                                          CASE WHEN accepted=1 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_) ELSE NULL END);
```